# Why loops in inline function cannot be properly auto-vectorized?

Tags: c++, inline, simd, clang++, auto-vectorization

I am trying to vectorize some simple calculations for speed up from SIMD architecture. However, I also want to put them as inline function because function calls and non-vectorized codes also take computation time. However, I cannot always achieve them at the same time. In fact, most of my inline functions fail to get auto-vectorized. Here is a simple test code that works:

```
inline void add1(double *v, int Length) {
    for(int i=0; i < Length; i++) v[i] += 1;
}

void call_add1(double v[], int L) {
    add1(v, L);
}

int main(){return 0;}
```

On Mac OS X 10.12.3, compile it:

```
clang++ -O3 -Rpass=loop-vectorize -Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize -std=c++11 -ffast-math test.cpp

test.cpp:2:5: remark: vectorized loop (vectorization width: 2, interleaved count: 2) [-Rpass=loop-vectorize]
    for(int i=0; i < Length; i++) v[i] += 1;
    ^
```

However, Something very similar (only moving arguments in call_add1) does not work:

```
inline void add1(double *v, int Length) {
    for(int i=0; i < Length; i++) v[i] += 1;
}

void call_add1() {
    double v[20]={0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; 
    int L=20;
    add1(v, L);
}

int main(){ return 0;}
```

Compiling with the same command produces no output. Why does this happen? How can I make sure that loops in inline functions always get auto-vectorized? I want to vectorize many function loops, so I hope the fix would not be to complex.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think some const correctness might go quite a long way here ...

Comment: Look at assembly code generated by compiler. The whole function may be optimized out, or result may be computed at compile time. Also, in the second case compiler knows that array is not large enough for vectorization. Just a guess.

Comment: This is pretty much C code, not C++.

Comment: @AlexF Thanks for the answer! I cannot understand assembly code. I tried to add the current time to the vector, but it still does not work. for (int i=0; i<L; i++) v[i] += double(time(0));

Comment: Again, small array with size known at compile time. Somewhat out of topic - if you are interesting in low level optimizations, you need to know at least a bit of Assembly. All real answers to such qiestions are there.

Comment: @AlexF It seems that you guessed correctly that the vector is not large enough. double *v = new double[200] works but 10 does not. Thanks!

Comment: Should have looked at the compiler's asm output, not just some log messages.  That works for any compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compiling your code with `-fsave-optimization-record` shows that the loop was unrolled and then eliminated.

```
--- !Passed
Pass:            loop-unroll
Name:            FullyUnrolled
DebugLoc:        { File: main.cpp, Line: 2, Column: 5 }
Function:        _Z9call_add1v
Args:            
  - String:          'completely unrolled loop with '
  - UnrollCount:     '20'
  - String:          ' iterations'
...
--- !Passed
Pass:            gvn
Name:            LoadElim
DebugLoc:        { File: main.cpp, Line: 2, Column: 40 }
Function:        _Z9call_add1v
Args:            
  - String:          'load of type '
  - Type:            double
  - String:          ' eliminated'
  - String:          ' in favor of '
  - InfavorOfValue:  '0.000000e+00'
```

If you put 4000 elements to the array, it will exceed optimizer threshold and clang will enable vectorization.

Comment: Ha-ha. Useful switch!

Answer (score 4):

That is because for the 2nd case compiler knows there are no side effects and optimizes everything out https://godbolt.org/g/CnojEi clang 4.0.0 with `-O3` leaves only:

```
call_add1():
  rep ret
main:
  xor eax, eax
  ret
```

And you get no marketing about the loop magic.

In the 1st case compiler does produce some body for the function, because the function does modify the argument. If you compiled this as an object file. You could link to this function, and it would work. I guess if the parameters would be const, then maybe the function would also be left with empty body.

When you print out the contents the programs are not identical but they both use vectorized instructions: https://godbolt.org/g/KF1kNt

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the compiler would simply unroll and optimize-away the loop, when `v` is specified explicitly. Which is a **good thing**: the code that does not have to be executed is the fastest.

To verify it's an optimization, you could try to make some of the variables volatile ([live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XpJhMOQ7mvI0yKEZ)).